# why is this file empty? this code should populate it with stuff

Tags: java

```
package stuff;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DataWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("mydata.txt");

        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file already exists");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
        output.println("data1");
        output.println("data2"");
        output.println("data3");
        output.println("data4");
        output.println("data5");
        output.println("data6");
        output.println(" data7");
        System.out.println("data8");
    }
}
```

This code creates a "mydata.txt" but does not populate it with anything.  Why isn't this working?  I've been trying to get this work for 3 weeks!

Answer (score 1):

your not closing the output variable

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("mydata.txt");
        if(file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file already exists");
            System.exit(1);

        }
         java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
        output.println("data1");
        output.println("data2");
        output.println("data3");
        output.println("data4");
        output.println("data5");
        output.println("data6");
        output.println(" data7");
        output.close();          //close<--------------------------------
        System.out.println("data8");
```

Comment: If you don't call `output.close()` the data might not get flushed to the file, which is apparently what was happening in your case.

Comment: Or `flush` it. By the way your program will also crash with a NullPointerException if the file is not found. Perhaps you should handle this. `throws` like the OP did was fine so I'm frankly confused by the addition of such a clumsy `catch` block.

Comment: sorry i just plugged it in really quick and used intellisense to autocomplete, ill change it back

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file with:

```
output.close();
```